# How can i use authentication decorator to solve authentication problem when not using action

Tags: django-rest-framework

I tried to use the authentication decorator , but it didn't work, here follows my code

```
class UserViewSet(CreateModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin, UpdateModelMixin, DestroyModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    print('enter')
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    @authentication_classes([JwtAuthorizationAuthentication,])
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('creat')
        print(request.query_params)
        return ('ok')
    
    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f'1{self.authentication_classes}')
        print('ok2')
        return Response('ok')
```

I just only want to use the JWTAuthentication  when using create and update actions, and no more authentication for other actions in the Viewset.

And I also try to write the decorators to solve the problem, but the auth_decorator not works

```
from functools import update_wrapper

def auth_wrapper(*authentications, validate_auth=True):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            self.authentication_classes=authentications
            print(self.authentication_classes)
            if validate_auth:
                print(f'request1:{request.user}')
                self.perform_authentication(request)
                print(f'request2:{request._user}')
                # print(type(self.perform_authentication(request)))
     
            return func(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
        return update_wrapper(wrapper, func)
    return decorator

def permission_wrapper(*permissions, validate_perm=True):
    def decorator(func):
        def wapper(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            self.permission_classes=permissions
            if validate_perm:
                self.check_permissions(request)
            return func(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
        return update_wrapper(wapper, func)
    return decorator
```

Can anyone help me solve the problem? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_authenticators(self):
    if is_post_method(post):
        return [JwtAuthorizationAuthentication,]
    return super().get_authenticators()
```

I solve the problem by the code above